# r - Iterating with 2 variables in for

Tags: r, for-loop

Is there a construct in R where we can iterate with two variables at the same time in R? Like so,

```
for(i in list1 and j in list2)
```

The list1 and list2 can be any iterable.

Comment: @DatamineR I don't think the OP wants to iterate over all combinations of list1 and list2, but rather to iterate over two lists of the same length simultaneously (first of each, second of each, etc)

Comment: @DavidRobinson has understood the question rightly.

Comment: This construct doesn't exist in R (not, for example, the way it does in Python, with `for i, j in zip(list1, list2):`. You could iterate an index (`for index in seq_along(list1) { i <- list1[[index]]; j <- list2[[index]];...`) though that might be unsatisfying. But if you give more details of the specific operation, there might be a better way to perform it without a for loop, such as vectorizing it or combining the variables into a data frame

Comment: Actually my two iteravles are a numeric vector with random numbers and a list of file names. Both are equal in length and i need to access both of them simultaneously. @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the contents of your for loop can be written as some kind of a function then you can use `mapply`.

```
a <- 1:10
b <- LETTERS[1:10]

a
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
b
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"

mapply(paste, a, b)
[1] "1 A"  "2 B"  "3 C"  "4 D"  "5 E"  "6 F"  "7 G"  "8 H"  "9 I"  "10 J"
```

Sure you will have to replace "paste" with a function that takes 2 elements (one from each list) as input. Also using more than 2 lists/vectors is ok.

Answer (score 11):

In general, iterating over multiple variables (of the same length) is best achieved using a single index that acts as an index for referencing elements (variables) in a list:

```
var_list <- list(
  var1 = 1:10,          # 1, ..., 10
  var2 = letters[17:26] # q, ..., z
)

for (i in 1:length(var_list$var1)) {

  # Process each of var1 and var2
  print(paste(
    'var1:', var_list$var1[i],
    '; var2:', var_list$var2[i]
  ))

}
```

Comment: How to do this in `ggplot()`? `aes()` does not seem to accept indexing.

Answer (score 11):

There's also the foreach package:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i = letters, j = LETTERS) %do% {
  paste(i,j)
}

[[1]]
[1] "a A"

[[2]]
[1] "b B"

[[3]]
[1] "c C"
etc...
```

This also has the advantage of being easy to parallelize: simply change the %do% to %dopar%, [register](https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html) a parallel back-end, and rock and roll.

Comment: This is the closest I've seen in R to the zip() construct in Python.